# How to find the limit of tension required to pull a body?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

If let us say you have a massless and on the other hand a mass string = 10g.

How should we find out the limit of tension that a person can apply to lift sth.

Q1 how much should be the limit(or limit of weight of the body that we are pulling) so that we can apply tension.

Q2 Same , how much should he limit of tension means when the string will break.What is the maximum amount force that a massless string can hold.

I am asking this because in almost every question , we are able to pull objects of very heavy mass when string is massless.How is that possible ?How do we approach that.

Answer (score 1):

In elementary mechanics problems we are often told that strings and ropes are “light”, “strong” and “inextensible”. “Light” means that the mass of the string is negligible, so that tension is the same all the way along the string. “Inextensible” means that we can assume the string will not stretch and “strong” means we can assume it will not break.

As you say, these are not realistic assumptions - all strings have mass and all strings will stretch and eventually break. But these assumptions allow us to find a solution that is good enough as a “first approximation” to a problem. There are models of strings that are more realistic (e.g you can assume the string has a constant mass per unit length, or it obeys [Hooke’s law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law)) but then problems become more difficult to solve - you need to be able to handle the simple cases first before you progress to more complex problems.

Comment: Ok.I understand your point.I have also been doing a lot of problems related to now.Want to know what formula can we only use or you know , just the equation how should we write in 3 cases that you wrote.It would be very helpful if you give me some guidance on that.

Comment: You know , How did we reach these assumptions actually.

Comment: @robertpatrick They are approximately true - ropes and strings do not stretch very much, and they are light compared to the loads that they support. And you have to start somewhere, and these assumptions make mechanics problems easier to solve. But they are not compulsory.